# How to replace only the selected text from SWT with new Text

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT Text widget. I have text inside the widget say for example "B for Bat" and I select(through mouse and key board) a part of it i.e. "Bat" and trigger an event through a button wherein i have my code to replace with "Ball" . So my final output would be "B for Ball".

How do I achieve this. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Replace");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            String content = text.getText();
            Point selection = text.getSelection();

            /* Get the first non-selected part, add "Ball" and get the second non-selected part */
            content = content.substring(0, selection.x) + "Ball" + content.substring(selection.y, content.length());

            text.setText(content);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400,shell.getSize().y);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The crucial part is using [`Text#getSelection()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html#getSelection%28%29), which will return a `Point` whose `x` coordinate is the start of the selection and the `y` coordinate is the end of the selection.

You might want to add a check for empty selections.

---

BTW: Please always post what you have tried yourself...